# mootools and sprite menu

Tags: javascript, mootools, css-sprites

i have a sprite tab menu that i would like to change the image when the user clicks, the problem is that i cant figure out how to do it properly, this is what i have:

```
<ul id="addCategoryList">
    <li  id='task' class="sprite-add-task-category-tasks menu-task "></li>
    <li  id='grades' class="sprite-add-task-category-tasks menu-grades-inactive">   </li>
    <li  id='results' class="sprite-add-task-category-tasks menu-results-inactive"></li>
    <li  id='other'  class="sprite-add-task-category-tasks menu-other-inactive"></li>
</ul>
```

and this is the javascript:

```
var getCategory = $('addCategoryList').getChildren();
getCategory.each(function(li){
    li.addEvent('click', function(){
        this.removeClass('menu-'+this.id+'-inactive').addClass('menu-'+this.id);
    });
});
```

the problem is that when i click it shows two categories as active as oppose to just the one that was clicked. i named them like that because they all share a common sprite and the only difference between the "menu-id-inactive" and 'menu-id" is the background position which makes the image appear as highlighted when the user clicks/

Answer (score 0):

this is not ideal as it does not render itself well to patterns. you really want to reverse it so you `.addClass('active')` rather than take away an inactive class that is not generic.

if your inactive class was generic, it could still work. as it stands, you need to keep state over what is active and before swapping the classes on the new active, you need to do undo the old active first.

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/z3nuq/

```
<ul id="addCategoryList">
    <li  id='task' class="sprite-add-task-category-tasks menu-task active">one</li>
    <li  id='grades' class="sprite-add-task-category-tasks menu-grades">two</li>
    <li  id='results' class="sprite-add-task-category-tasks menu-results">three</li>
    <li  id='other'  class="sprite-add-task-category-tasks menu-other">four</li>
</ul>
```

and then state:

```
(function() {
    var cList = $('addCategoryList'),
        active = cList.getElement('li.active');

    cList.getElements('li').each(function(li){
        li.addEvent('click', function(){
            active && active.removeClass('active')
            active = this.addClass('active');
        });
    });

})();
```

though strictly speaking - you can just do in the click `cList.getElements('.active').removeClass('active')` before you add the active class to the clicked el.

Answer (score 0):

Dimitar I agree with most everything, but I feel this approach is better:

http://jsfiddle.net/z3nuq/2/

Basic differences? No need to test for class active, just toggle it.

2nd uses event delegation. attach one event not potentially dozens

3rd feel free to dynamically add items to your list! Event will already be there

4th less code and I hate typing despite what this long winded post might suggest

:)

CODE Difference is only in JS

```
var cList = $$('#addCategoryList');
cList.addEvent('click:relay(li)', function(e,el){
    el.toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: this does not remove the active state on the previous active. $$("#id") returns a collection which then does a .each to apply the addEvent - though doing it via delegation can probably be a good thing - given that it does not mess with click behaviours within the menu items themselves. to be honest - sometimes more is more and less is shortsighted and harder to read/maintain. avoid overoptimising at the expense of func or readability  :)

Comment: misread where only on li could/should be active. Still think event delegation is the way to go and not an over optimization in this case :) Hope all is well D!